# No network, no USB, how to back up files from encrypted home directory

Tags: networking, usb, encryption

I cannot boot normally; when the system asks me to enter the key to decrypt the disk I cannot type anywhere and have to force a shutdown.

Upon restarting, I can go into recovery mode, and from there 'resume' and end up at a desktop that I can log into. However, the desktop loses the left and top Unity menu/sidebars, does not recognize USB drives, and only has loopback defined as a network interface. Attempting to add eth0 and wlan0 results in an error: "Error getting hardware address for "wlan0": No such device"

I can boot off of a CD (which gives me USB/network) and mount/decrypt the main disk, but then cannot decrypt the contents of /home.

I was planning on wiping this system and reinstalling but need to get some of the most recently changed files backed up first, and am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's what worked:

1. Boot into recovery mode, resume, log in. Open a terminal. Copy data from /home to /opt (or really anywhere outside of /home). Reboot.
2. Boot off of live CD. Plug in external drive. Mount encrypted filesystem (good instructions here: https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/how-to-mount-luks-encrypted-partitions-manually/). Copy files from encrypted filesystem to external drive.

Rinse, repeat.

Comment: I am happy that you found the solution. Please copy  and paste the instructions from the linked reference into your answer. Keep the link for further details. Blogs tend to disappear.  This way it will help others even it the original blog goes away.  Best